# Colpitts oscillator: how to reduce amplitude thermal drift?

Tags: analog, oscillator, thermal, oscillation, signal-theory

I have built this circuit, supply ±12V:

[image: Colpitts Oscillator circuit]

I am using a LM6172 amplifier.

I have found the transfer function of the filter involved:

\$H(j\omega)=\frac{1}{1 + \frac{R_3}{R_1} - L\omega^2(C_2+C_1\frac{R_3}{R_1})+j(\frac{L\omega}{R_1} - R_3C_1C_2\omega^2(L\omega-\frac{1}{C_e \omega}))}\$

Upon my calculations, the gain provided by the op amp should be of ~1 but it didn't start and I had to increase the gain to 1.8 (R2/R1). Also, without the R4 resistor the op amp is acting strangely, saturates - very high peak to peak amplitude - and oscillates at very high frequency (10 times the one of the oscillator) and heats a lot.

My problem is that the amplitude of the oscillations - at 1MHz - is very unstable as temperature varies slightly.

I just have to blow on the ciruit to change the peak-to-peak amplitude by ~2V

I also tried with thsese values:

\$R_1=1k\Omega,R_2=10k\Omega\$

But I got the same behaviour.

I don't know if the problem comes from the resistors as they change of value with little temperature variations or if it comes from the op amp directly.

Maybe I have badly chosen the values of the components?

**Is there a way to reduce this amplitude thermal drift of this circuit?**

**UPDATE:** I just figured I was using carbon film resistors which have a high temperature coefficient. I will try to replace them by metal film resistors.**Results:** Didn't change anything.

Comment: Don’t you know how to compute reactive impedance and load resistance?  Make R1,R2 about 100 x bigger e.g 1M, 10M respectively. You are on the verge of insufficient gain for no oscillation,

Comment: Or 1000x bigger than 1k, 10k

Comment: That is why thermally stable oscillators use Crystal's and some use temperature controlled ovens. A purely analog oscillator cannot be temperature stable over a wide range.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I don't understand how making R1 and R2 100 times bigger would make any difference since the op amp gain -absolute- is given by \$\frac{R_2}{R_1}\$. In the datasheet of the LM6172, it's specified that low  feedback resistor values - about 1k ohms - are recommanded at high frequencies. According to the transfer function of the filter which seems to be correct after simulator tests, with those values, op amp gain is supposed to be about 1 because the filter is near gain resonance frquency.

Comment: @Sparky256 Thanks for the informations. My biggest problem is that the temperature variations are really tiny. I'd say 1 or 2°C are enough to make in big change in amplitude. Do you think I should try a crystal?

Comment: I induced indicated your design was overloaded (damped) the other reason is Q = R/L and your values indicate extreme poor Quality Factor. Of course a Xtal would be  and 1000x better and the load R must be >=1M but a simple CMOS inverter is all you need.   L has a huge PTC but so does C but it’s not just the R it’s everything so fundamtalky wrong with this design without any complete specs!!

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I must admit I don't understand what is "fundamentally wrong". I have drawn with Python the [Bode plot](https://imgur.com/a/0LgdvWM) of the filter and the purple dot represents the oscillation frequency \$f_0=\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{1}{R_1R_3C_1C_2}+\frac{1}{LC_e}}\$. The phase plot shows a strong slope at the desired frequency which translates a good selectivity? In real world, I get good oscillations with pretty pure sine wave according to my oscilloscope FFT. Also [this simulation](http://tinyurl.com/y3obhzgx) works well.

Comment: I did not do math for you but could prove why you do not have enough gain for the Barkhausen criteria for reliable oscillation so take my word for it please . Did you compute the transfer functions for linear sine?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I am wasting your time. I believe you about my wrong doing but I don't know what linear sine is. I think the sine function is not linear and don't know what concept is behind this. I just took the modulus and the angle of the complex transfer function of my first post and plotted it with frequency as variable

Comment: You have no experience and a belief . Good luck . I have 45 yrs of bleed edge experience

Comment: You are wasting your time is more like it.

Comment: I really didn't want to offend you I wanted to apologize for not understanding what you were saying. Thank you for your help anyways

Comment: Ask a better question if you wish to learn, don’t make false assumptions on your problem. I’m not offended but you aren’t learning to do what I said. You will never find a Colpitt’s Osc with a low Rin as you have.

Comment: I will try to replace R1 and R3 with higher values. I have mainly inspired my circuit from [this one](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/oscillator-osc43.gif) from [this page](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/oscillator/colpitts.html)
Maybe they are using too weak values too?

Answer (score 2):

The voltage offset of the amplifier is changing as well as most of your components. Make sure they all have low temperature coefficient's.

[image]

Another problem with the Colpitts oscillator is the use of magnetic elements, they must be properly shielded (which can be difficult with magnetic fields.)

This might be a better oscillator. I've seen them used in high stability applications. use low TC resistors, a low TC amp and a [polypropylene](https://www.electronics-notes.com/articles/electronic_components/capacitors/polypropylene.php) capacitor.  There are much less components to worry about (and less TC's) and much less interference from magnetic noise.

[image]

Another problem with either oscillator is the capacitors, capacitors can act like microphones and pick up vibrations, polyproplene capacitors are less susceptible to this effect.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I will definitely try this circuit